# Populate ASP.Net CheckBoxList ClientSide using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i'm following the instructions found at http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/120224/Populate-ASPNet-CheckBoxList-ClientSide-using-jQuery-AJAX/

This does populate the checkbox list however the any label clicked will check or uncheck the first item in the checkbox list. how do i fix the code to let the "for" label point to the correct checkbox 
the JavaScript returns xml

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkaddressemails" Width="300px" runat="server">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>



 function GetDropDownData(o) {

            var ddlTestDropDownListXML = document.getElementById(o.id);


            // Provide Some Table name to pass to the WebMethod as a parameter.
            var tableName = ddlTestDropDownListXML.options[ddlTestDropDownListXML.selectedIndex].value;


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Reports.aspx/GetDropDownItems",
                data: '{tableName: "' + tableName + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var customers = xml.find("Table1");
                    var row = $("[id*=chkaddressemails] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                    $("[id*=chkaddressemails] tr").remove();
                    $.each(customers, function () {
                        var customer = $(this);

                        $("input", row).val($(this).find("Email").text());
                        $("label", row).html($(this).find("Grouping").text()); 

                        $("[id*=chkaddressemails] tbody").append(row);
                        row = $("[id*=chkaddressemails] tr:last-child").clone(true);

                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please flatten the ASP into HTML so that we'll have a [mcve]?

Comment: the url above is what i'm using http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/120224/Populate-ASPNet-CheckBoxList-ClientSide-using-jQuery-AJAX/

Comment: You need to set the "for" attribute of the label before you append the rows, you are cloning and using the same element with the same attribute over and over.

Comment: can you show me what that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer. the ajax calls a static function that returns a datatable converted to xml.
I then clear the old data out and repopulate the checkboxlist. I also get the values and place it into a textbox.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddladdresscustomers" Width="300px" AutoPostBack="false" onchange="GetDropDownData(this);" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

     function GetDropDownData(o) {

            var ddlTestDropDownListXML = document.getElementById(o.id);


            // Provide Some Table name to pass to the WebMethod as a parameter.
            var tableName = ddlTestDropDownListXML.options[ddlTestDropDownListXML.selectedIndex].value;


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Reports.aspx/GetDropDownItems",
                data: '{tableName: "' + tableName + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var customers = xml.find("Table1");

                    var table = $('<table></table>');
                    var counter = 0;
                    var customer = $(this);
                    $.each(customers, function () {




                        table.append($('<tr></tr>').append($('<td></td>').append($('<input>').attr({
                            type: 'checkbox', name: 'chklistitem', value: $(this).find("Email").text(), id: 'chklistitem' + counter
                        })).append(
                        $('<label>').attr({
                            for: 'chklistitem' + counter++
                        }).text($(this).find("Grouping").text()))));
                    });

                    var y = $('#<%= chkaddressemails.ClientID %>');   
                    getallfromcheckbox();
                    removeCheckBoxItem();
                    y.append(table);

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }

function removeCheckBoxItem()
{



    $("[id*=chkaddressemails] :checkbox").parent().remove();

}
        function getallfromcheckbox()
{
            var retur = '';

                var y = $('#<%= txtaddressemail.ClientID %>');
            var names = [];
            $('[id*=chkaddressemails] input:checked').each(function () {
                names.push(this.name);

                retur += (this.value) +';';

            });


            document.getElementById("<%= txtscheduleemail.ClientID %>").value = retur;
        }
```